# What are the active reload effects on GOW3 weapons?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

What are the effects of active reloading weapons?

Extra damage, extra range or both? Are the effects the same for every weapon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Active reloading allows you to reload the gun faster than normal. This is achieved by tapping to reload and the tapping reload again when the reload tracker is anywhere within a grey bar highlighted on the reload gauge.

A "perfect" active reload is achieved when you tap the reload button within a much narrower white bar on the reload gauge. This fills the empty rounds in your click with special shots, indicated by flashing ammo symbols (for guns with bullets). [The damage per shot is also increased by around 8%.](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Active_Reload) (Except for the Scorcher).

These special shots have differing effects for some guns (*paraphrased from above link)*:

- **Hammerburst II** - Gets only 15 rounds in its magazine instead of the usual 17.
- **Boltok** - Rate of fire increase.
- **Torque Bows** - Charge up faster.
- **Boomshot** - Receives an aftershock of mini explosions.
- **Scorcher** - Receives a range increase.

As [wilerson](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4007/wilerson) noted in the comments, if you click reload anywhere outside of the white or grey bar, before the reload is complete, then you achieve a "failed" reload. This confers no bonuses and increases the time it takes to reload the gun, such that it would have been faster to do nothing after starting the reload.

To summarise: Any active reload will cut down reload times. A perfect reload will grant bonus damage and some extra effects depending on the type of gun. A failed reload will increase reload times.

Comment: Good answer. I was starting to write mine when yours popped up. I would only add that, if the reload button is tapped when the reload tracker is not on the highlighted grey bar, there's a "failed" active reload, which makes the weapon jam and take longer to reload than if you hadn't tried to use an Active Reload.

Comment: @Wilerson, good point, I'll add that in :)

Comment: It might also be worth a mention that there is a _Super Reload_ mutator that can be unlocked and then used in Horde and Arcade mode. Enabling this mutator will increase the damage further and increase the clip size when an active reload is performed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the One Shot, it's after effect being able to penetrate through multiple opponents. (Also goes through a Maulers Shield)